# Complex Equation Containing Sums of 3rd Roots of Unity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose I have 
$$\alpha_k=\frac{1}{3^k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(1+w_3^{j+2}+w_3^{2j+1}\right)$$
where $w_3=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$, I am looking for complex $z$ such that 
$$z^n=\alpha_{n+1}$$
Now I know that $1+w_3^{j+2}+w_3^{2j+1}=3$ if $j\equiv{1\mod{(3)}}$ and $0$ otherwise. if I consider the polar form, then
$$1+w_3^{j+2}+w_3^{2j+1}=1+e^{\frac{2ij\pi}{3}}e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}+e^{\frac{4ij\pi}{3}}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}=1+e^{\frac{2i(j+2)\pi}{3}}+e^{\frac{2i(2j+1)\pi}{3}}$$
But this is not getting me any closer, since now I have a binomial term in  front and a sumation still.  If I break it up in to three summands I get
$$z^{k-1}=\alpha_k=\frac{2^k}{3^k}+\frac{e^\frac{4i\pi}{3}(e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}+1)^k}{3^k}+\frac{e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}(e^\frac{4i\pi}{3}+1)^k}{3^k}$$
And it is from here I get stuck.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:  I'm aware that the solutions would just be $z=\sqrt[m]{a_{m+1}}$.  I'm looking for expressions or solutions that contain the 3rd roots of unity; $1, w_3, w_3^2$, that do NOT depend on $k$.  I didn't express this when I originally posted this.

Comment: I think you should replace $\binom{n}{k}$ in the first line with $\binom{k}{j}$. You are computing three times the probability that a random subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ has a cardinality $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Consider that $1+w_3$ is a sixth root of unity.

Comment: would the fact that it is a 3rd root of unity for $(z-1)^3=1$ help out?  Since $2, 1+w_3,$ and $1+w^2$ are involved then?

Comment: $n\mapsto\frac{1+w^n+w^{2n}}{3}$ is a function that equals $1$ if $n$ is a multiple of three, zero otherwise. Moreover, $\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}a^j = (1+a)^k$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Okay, I"ve done some work, but I'm still struggling to get it.  I know now that  $$z^{k-1}=\frac{2^k+w_3^2(w_3+1)^k+w_3(w_3^2+1)^k}{3^k}$$ but I'm not sure how your hints are leading me to water.  Any way you can help some more?

Comment: $w_3^2(w_3+1)^k$ is a point on the unit circle and $w_3(w_3^2+1)^k$ is just the conjugate. That expression is a periodic function.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this does it from here. It took me a second, and I knew what I was looking at, but couldn't wrap my head around it.